# How to configure DNS to point a subdomain to a server?

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, centos, godaddy

I need to setup a dns record to point a subdomain to a server. atm I am using godaddy's dns, and I have an "A" record to point to the main server and I need to point fs.domain.com to another server. What records do I need to add?

Answer (score 4):

The simple answer is you need to add an `A` record for `fs` to the your domain.  You* may want to add MX and SPF (TXT) records for the domain, but they are not required.

EDIT:  Add the MX record if the domain will be sending and/or receiving email.  Otherwise leave it off.

SPF records help prevent use of your domain by spammers.  If the domain does not send email then an SPF record like `v=spf1 -all` clearly indicates that the domain should not be used for email.  As MXs are required accept email, I also use SPF to filter out spoofed or owned servers which are sending email.  I set an SPF policy for all my domains.

I started publishing SPF records after a domain was hijacked by spammers.  Adding the SPF records helped reduce the backscatter spam, and appeared to drive the spammers off the domain.  (Bad news for spammers, other spammers harvested the addresses used.  The addresses are blocked but still receive spam years later.)

Comment: what are the advantages of having a MX and SPF records?

Comment: I would say that adding MX and SPF records (which are required for emails) are un-nessesary for a subdomain except in specific circumstances. Like you want to receive mail on that subdomain.

Comment: If he's going to configure SPF for one subdomain that he doesn't use for mail anyways, he might be better off creating a wildcard SPF record (*.domain.com), to prevent spoofing of any subdomain.